# Responsive equal height divs

Tags: jquery

I have four side-by-side divs containing approximately the same amount of text, but some browsers render the text slightly differently so as to make some of the divs taller/shorter than the others.

I know there are jQuery plugins that let you set a number of divs to be the same height as the highest one, but my website is responsive, and the height of the divs changes for the tablet and mobile 'versions' of the responsive site.

Is there a way to set these four divs so that they are all the height of the tallest one, and as the browser is resized to trigger the layout to switch to the tablet or mobile version, the divs will be able to adjust their size accordingly, and once again all be made to be equal in height to the tallest of the divs?

Answer (score 1):

```
function resizeMy4Div(){
    var maxHeight = 0;
    $my4div.css("height","auto").each(function()
    {   var h = $(this).height();
        if(h > maxHeight) maxHeight = h;
    }).height(maxHeight);
}

$(window).on("resize",resizeMy4Div);
resizeMy4Div();
```

Comment: Not sure how this solves the problem. Once the browser is resized so that the tablet version is shown, the function won't change anything because all of the divs will be the same height, and if the tablet version's content is shorter or taller compared to the desktop version, the 4 containing divs will not be resized accordingly.

Comment: so, $my4div.css("height","auto").each(... to reset their size before ?

Comment: I thought about that possibility, but wouldn't that cause the heights to be constantly jumping back and forth between the original heights and the tallest height as you're resizing the window? I haven't tried it to see for myself but surely it would be noticeable, at least on slower computers?

Comment: if div content is wrapped you can check content height and set all wrap sizes to the max height ? without any height:auto

Answer (score 0):

ok, here is a second solution, but it's assume the bigger div is always the same :- )

```
var biggerDiv = $();
var maxHeight = 0;

$my4div.each(function()
{   var $t = $(this);
    var h = $t.height();
    if(h > maxHeight)
    {   maxHeight = h;
        $biggerDiv = $t;
    }
}).not($biggerDiv).height(maxHeight);

$(window).on("resize",function()
{   $my4div.not($biggerDiv).height($biggerDiv.height());
});
```